# How do I calculate the position and rotation where 3 given vectors would intersect 3 given points

Tags: mathematics, trigonometry

I have 3 normalized directional vectors and 3 points.

The 3 vectors are all attached to the same object, and I would like them to keep their angles relative to each other.

I want to find a location and rotation that I can use for the parent object that would make the vectors all point to their respective points.

I either didn't pay enough attention in school, or wasn't taught the math I need to solve this on my own. This is what I've figured out so far:

1. For any 2 points in 2D space, given 2 vectors, there is a whole "arc" of locations+rotations that satisfy the conditions. Here is a representation of the problem in 2D with the small black arrows representing my vectors, the black circle representing my parent object, "A." and "B." representing my points, and the gray spheres representing a sample of valid points.
   [image: 2D version]
2. This 2D relationship between the 2 vectors and 2 points can be represented in 3D with a surface by rotating the arc of valid points around the axis that goes between point A and B:
   [image: 2D version in 3D]
3. Adding a third vector and a third point, I want to find the location and rotation on that surface where vector C points the closest to point C, intersecting if possible.
   [image: Desired solution]

Comment: It looks to me like you can form three of those clementine-shaped surfaces, one for each pair of points, and look for an intersection in all three.

Comment: Oh, that is a really good idea.
Even if they don't all intersect, there will definitely be an intersection between AB and BC, BC and CA, and CA and AB. I could use those to find a transform that intersects 2, and is closest to the third.
Do you happen to know any helpful math keywords for me to look up so I can finish figuring this out? I don't actually know how to describe the shape with an equation.

Comment: It's a circular arc, revolved around the chord joining its endpoints, yes? I think that makes this the outer surface of a self-intersecting torus. If the direction vectors are perpendicular, then this becomes just a sphere.

Comment: Yes, I did notice that with a right angle between the vectors, it makes a circle/sphere. I'll see if I can learn the math I need from here.